# SBI (python script for Google search by image) is not working today

Tags: google-image-search

I had been using sbi to do Google search by Image from own webpage, in order to extract the best guess. It has been working well. Yesterday worked well..

Today, when I ran the program, it got errors.

**My Code:**

```
import sbi
result = bi.search_by(url='http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/apple/apple-09.jpg')
print result.best_guess
```

**Errors:**

```
File "/Users/Documents/workspace/src/imagesearch.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = sbi.search_by(url='http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/apple/apple-09.jpg')

File "/Users/Envs/code1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sbi.py", line 154, in search_by
    url = a['href']

File "/Users/Envs/code1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to sbi.py file, comment out line 129-171.